# newline interpretation in bash script

Tags: bash, newline, printf

I wrote a little script that simulates someone typing the user input onto the screen.

It works great, as long as there isn't a newline.  I can't seem to figure out how to alter my script to make this work, and I know it has to be simple.

I'm also open to a complete refactoring if someone has a better way of scripting this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Displays input as if someone were typing it

read the_input_line

while [ -n "$the_input_line" ]
        do
                printf "%c" "$the_input_line"
                sleep .1
                the_input_line=${the_input_line#?}
done
```

Comment: I should clarify - I THINK it's newline character that is messing it up.  It breaks on a newline if you do something like (the program is called typewriter):  ls -la | typewriter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only reads one line. This loops over all lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Displays input as if someone were typing it

while read the_input_line
do
  while [ -n "$the_input_line" ]
  do
    printf "%c" "$the_input_line"
    sleep .1
    the_input_line=${the_input_line#?}
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: Yes.  That's so simple.  I tried so many weird hacks, but didn't think to do a nested loop like that.  Very cool, thanks a lot dude.